# Is it illegal to not using Google Static Map trademark?

Tags: google-maps, watermark, google-maps-static-api

I am planning to use google static map to build a tile map something similar to pokemon go. but the google logo appears on the bottom of every tile and it turn out to look very bad.

Is it ok for me to cut out the downloaded google map image and only using the upper part (which doesn't have the logo in it) to build my map?

does it against a specific google term?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for legal advice.

Comment: You are not allowed to do that. The google terms prohibit this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the [Google Map Terms and Conditions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#8-licenses-from-google-to-you)  section 8.4 b viii

> Restrictions. In using Google Brand Features, you will not:
>
> remove, distort, or alter any element of a Google Brand Feature
>   (including squeezing, stretching, inverting, or discoloring).

and section 8.5

> Proprietary Rights Notices. You will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark
>   notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) displayed or provided
>   through the Service. Where such notices are not displayed or provided
>   within the Service, you must display such notices according to the
>   Maps APIs Documentation.

So in short it is illegal.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. :)

Comment: Do you know whether google has any paid term that I can use the map without the logo?

Comment: I don't know of any such term but I don't google would allow maps to be used without their logo.

Comment: There's a difference between "violates the terms and conditions" and "illegal". The Google Map Terms and Conditions are not the law.  Your answer is fine except for the conclusion "So in short it is illegal", which crosses into offering inaccurate legal advice.

Comment: This site is not about legal questions. From the question it is apparent that the user wants to know whether he is allowed  to remove the logo or not. "violates the terms and conditions" and "illegal" both mean that it is not legal and he is not allowed to do it. If he wanted expert legal advise  he would have consulted a lawyer rather than add a question on stackoverflow.